# Unable to find an entry point named

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am coding an application in c# that makes use of a third-party dll coded in cpp. I make several calls to the dll, and they all are working except for one.

My code makes the call in the following manner:

```
return ObjectGetStringEntryID(pObject, strEntryID, strEntryID.Capacity);

[DllImport(EXTERNAL_DLL, CharSet = DefaultCharSet)]
protected static extern bool ObjectGetStringEntryID(IntPtr pObject, StringBuilder strEntryID, int nMaxLength);
```

Since I have access to the source code, I know it contains the following definition:

```
BOOL ObjectGetStringEntryID(CMAPIObject* pObject, LPTSTR szEntryID, int nMaxLength)
```

As stated before, I make several other calls to this dll using the same format, and they are successful.

Consequently, I have the following setting if it helps:

```
public const CharSet DefaultCharSet = CharSet.Ansi;
```

Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong in my call? From the same class, I call:

```
MessageGetSubject(pObject, strSubject, strSubject.Capacity);

[DllImport(EXTERNAL_DLL, CharSet = DefaultCharSet)]
protected static extern void MessageGetSubject(IntPtr pMessage, StringBuilder strSubject, int nMaxLength);
```

Which matches up to the method:

```
void MessageGetSubject(CMAPIMessage* pMessage, LPTSTR szSubject, int nMaxLength)
```

This comes from the same classes in both c# and cpp as the call that is not working, but it works just fine. There does not appear to be any difference in how it is called, so they both should either work or not work.

If anyone has any insight into what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: since your C# declarations are different, why do you expect them to be the same

Comment: I put the second sample there to show that I was calling in the same way, and it was working. It is not an issue with the dll not being found. In another class, I have calls that are made with sending all of the same variables. With those, the only difference is the method name, but they are also called properly.

Comment: Do you mean to pass the StringBuilder or did you intend to pass a string?

Comment: @Pete, the documenhtation says that it is the StringBuilder that needs to be passed. I found that odd too, but it works in other methods with a similar signature.

Comment: Try changing Charset to CharSet.Ansi. You might also take a shot at passing a string instead of stringbuilder... My guess is stringbuilder is fine, but never hurts to try stuff.

Comment: @Pete, thank you. I tried sending a string, but no dice. Good idea, though. DefaultCharSet is actually defined as CharSet.Ansi. I have quite a few calls to the DLL, which is why I set constants. I think I'll change my second set of code to show one of the methods that better match the signature. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: I get an exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred.

Comment: Is the calling convention specified explicitly in the DLL Export? You could try adding CallingConvention=CallingConvention.(Cdecl or StdCall) as appropriate to the Import. Just fyi StringBuilder is needed for strings that get written to by the DLL but passing strings wouldn't cause the missing entry point problem.

Comment: @TheMathmagician thanks for the explanation on that. It would never occur to me to send a string and have it changed as C# strings are immutable. I never would have considered StringBuilder for that. Cool.

Comment: @TheMathemagician, the calling convention does not seem to be explicitly set, but if there was a problem with this, wouldn't it affect all method calls? I am trying to make no changes to the cpp, as my skills in it are basic and have not been practiced for 15 years. Plus, when I build the cpp dll, I need to make a x64 and x86 build, and it took a while to get the architecture changed last time. That is not nearly as easy as changing it for C#. I will, of course, make the change if you think there is a high probability that this is the problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas. Yes logically it would affect all method calls but perhaps it's guessing correctly for most? Or for some data types it doesn't matter? It's just something to try.

Comment: You are correct; it is worth the try. Where would I add this? As I said, my cpp is a bit rusty (like a bicycle that has fallen into the ocean). Again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `EntryPointNotFoundException` means that the symbol `ObjectGetStringEntryID` is not exported by the DLL. Check the export file (or __declspec declaration) to make sure it is exported, and by that name. You can also use the Depends tool to look at the DLLs exports.

Comment: @Tergiver, where would the export file be, and could I add the method directly to it if it is missing? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It would be a .def file. This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx

Comment: @Tergiver, I used the VS Object browser and noticed that this method only had one entry under the Global Functions section, while all of the others had two. I tracked this down to a missing line in the header file, and added 'AFX_EXT_CLASS BOOL ObjectGetStringEntryID(CMAPIObject* pObject, LPTSTR szEntryID, int nMaxLength);'. The method now shows up twice in the object browser, but the new dll still gives me the same error. I feel I am on the correct track, but I guess this was not what you were talking about.

Comment: @Tergiver, My mistake! I grabbed the dll from debug rather than release. When I took the correct dll, it worked! Thank you everyone for your help. I'm not sure how to mark Tergiver as the correct answer as this was all done in comments.

Comment: Great, I made it an answer to mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EntryPointNotFoundException` means that the symbol `ObjectGetStringEntryID` is not exported by the DLL. Check the export file (or __declspec declaration) to make sure it is exported, and by that name.

This may help: [Exporting from a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx)